# Maven Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found

Tags: plugins, maven-2, assemblies, maven-assembly-plugin

Following [**this Guide**](http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-openimaj-using-maven.html) I ran the command

```
mvn assembly:assembly
```

and got the `Build Failure` of

```
Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
```

I've looked at numerous questions on this, but to no avail.

From [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463721/maven-assembly-error-reading-assemblies), I created a `.xml` with this inside:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/README*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/services</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/services</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

and included this in the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

but still no luck.

I'm pretty new to this as you can probably tell, how can I get this running?

**~~EDIT~~**

In the `pom.xml` I changed

```
<descriptor>jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
```

To

```
<descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
```

**~~EDIT 2~~**

`pom.xml` now contains this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

**~~EDIT 3~~**

This `pom.xml` now works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183460/error-reading-assemblies-no-assembly-descriptors-found)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this to work, you need to create the file `jar-with-dependencies.xml` in `src/main/assembly/` and this XML:

```
<descriptors>
    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

i.e. you need to specify the path to the file and the convention is to put the files into `src/main/assembly/`.

To use the ones provided by Maven, you need to use the `descriptorRef` element instead (wrapped in a `descriptorRefs`).

Also don't put the descriptor inside of the `execution` element or `mvn assembly:assembly` can't find it anymore (since you specifically moved it to the `mvn package` target).

**[EDIT]** I followed the tutorial myself and there is an important point which you might have missed: You need to select the correct archetype. In my case, that was `5` but the order can change. So read the whole list and look for the string `openimaj-quickstart-archetype` or things will break.

Comment: I cant find a `src/assembly/`

Comment: @MLMLTL You need to create this folder.

Comment: @MLMLTL: I checked again with one of my project; see my edits. If you created a custom XML file, you need to use `descriptor` and the path to the file (relative to `${basedir}`).

Comment: Again, still no luck -- PS `</descriptor` needs a `>`?

Comment: Why are you using a beta version of the plugin? The latest release is `2.5.3`. Try that

Comment: Run `mvn -X` to get debug output. That should show you the absolute path which the plugin searches. Also check the documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html And `help:effective-pom` can show you the POM as Maven actually sees it.

Comment: `No goals have been specified for this build` - So added that in (see edit) but is still saying that now

Comment: Try `mvn assembly:assembly -X` :-)

Comment: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta5:assembly (default-cli) ... Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found`

Comment: You're still using the old version of the plugin. The syntax in EDIT 2 should work. Are you executing Maven in the correct folder?

Comment: How do I check that? I've `cd`'d into the project folder so it should be, right? - With the `2.5.3` still no different either.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183460/error-reading-assemblies-no-assembly-descriptors-found

Comment: Thank You! It was the putting of `<configuration>` above the `<executions>` that solved it, submit it as an answer if you like :)

Comment: The fully qualified name of the class which contains the `main(String[])` method.

Comment: Where do I get the `main(String[]) method` name from?

Comment: The class name should be mentioned in the OpenIMAJ tutorial; isn't there a `pom.xml` in the sources already?

Comment: [I cant see it](http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-openimaj-using-maven.html) and there are many poms, inside of which I don't know where to look

Comment: You probably chose the wrong archetype when creating the tutorial. Make sure you chose `openimaj-quickstart-archetype` when Maven asks which archetype you want (first question).

Comment: I dont have a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` anywhere

Comment: Any why is that a problem?