# Maven: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to compile a project with Maven. I have used this command `mvn assembly:assembly` and I get the following error. This is with OPENIMAJ. I use option 7 (`7: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)`) as an archtype.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.021 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-27T17:19:42+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) on project tester: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183460/error-reading-assemblies-no-assembly-descriptors-found)

Comment: @hermitmaster The answer did not solve my question.